# iOS: Web preferences for UIWebView?

Tags: ios

On Mac OS/X, you can programmatically set the default font and many other values in a WebView by settings its web preferences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To set the font you could just use CSS and JavaScript. Do the following in the UIWebView page loaded delegate event to set the default font size on any page:

```
NSInteger fontSizePercent = 150;
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<style>body {font-size: %i%% !important}</style>'", fontSizePercent];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

Only problem is that you may get a flash of the normal font size briefly before your script is run.

Comment: Yes, that will help with fonts, but what about other settings like cache policy?

Comment: Indeed. There are many useful things that can be set through WebPreferences on Mac. I am assuming there is a parallel way on iOS but I haven't found it yet.